# Moving from acceleration- gravity equivalence to general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, acceleration, relativity

Einstein's happiest thought of his life led to so called acceleration-gravity equivalence by simply imagining a man free falling. This simple thought led Einstein to formulate his general theory of relativity. But I want to know how mathematically he came up with the conclusion such as gravity is interpreted as a curvature in the fabric Of space and time using this principle.

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration-gravity equivalence is the basis notion of GR.

All that high school problems, where it is said to take a constant $g=9.8m/s^2$ can be solved in the same way if we imagine a flat earth accelerating upwards at this rate.

Curvature of spacetime enters in the game when that simplification is not more possible. $g$ is clearly smaller at $1000 km$ above earth surface, and its direction in New York is not parallel to its direction in San Francisco.

So, curvature of spacetime is the GR mathematical treatment of the non uniformity of gravity acceleration.